# Flutter - How to hide or change widget as seen in Recent Apps overview

Tags: security, flutter

I'm developing a Flutter application that deals with cryptocurrency (a wallet). Some people have requested that the app takes some measures to hide their balance, etc.

The one thing I can't figure out, however, is hiding information from the recent apps menu (like secure window mode on Android, or simply changing the interface so balance isn't visible.)

I added a `WidgetsBindingObserver` to my main widget and tried something like:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  switch (state) {
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      setState(() {
          _hideBalance = true;
      });
      super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      setState(() {
          _hideBalance = false;
      });
      super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
      break;
    default:
      super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
      break;
  }
}

@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
}

@override
void dispose() {
   WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
   super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _hideBalance ? SizedBox() : Text("$12,234");
}
```

However, this has no effect on the recent apps which appears to be an exact snapshot from the moment the home button was pressed (on my OnePlus 6T at least). E.g. - I can still see the balance in the recent apps/app switcher overview.

Is there a way to do this with flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying this function is not called? If yes, you need to add the following,

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
}

@override
void dispose() {
   WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
   super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: No sorry, the function is called - but it doesn't have an effect of the appearance in recent apps. E.g. `_hideBalance` hides the balance when it's `true`, if I removed the `resumed` case then the balance would be hidden still after resuming the app - it's just not hidden in the Android "recent apps" overview.

Comment: The reason is, even though the state has changed, the build function is not called, therefore, the UI is not refreshed. I am not aware of a way to refresh the UI when the app is not active.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the Native Platform implementation of it. There is something called as window manager in android which you have to set it.

Paste this in MainActivity file and you should see it working.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, 
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

 }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this package to your pubspec.yaml [privacy_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/privacy_screen)

Then just add this code to your main:

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await PrivacyScreen.instance.enable(
    iosOptions: const PrivacyIosOptions(
      enablePrivacy: true,
      privacyImageName: "LaunchImage",
      lockTrigger: IosLockTrigger.didEnterBackground,
    ),
    androidOptions: const PrivacyAndroidOptions(
      enableSecure: true,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
    blurEffect: PrivacyBlurEffect.light,
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
```

Comment: this should be marked as an answer